# Select statement inside CASE - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, case

I am trying to figure out the right code for the below logic. If there is a certain value in the first column, display the value from the second column for that specific record.
Can someone please help? Thanks.

```
CASE WHEN TableA.Column1 = 'a' THEN 'select TableA.Column2 '
     WHEN TableA.Column4 = 'b' THEN 'select TableA.Column5'

     ELSE TableA.Column6
END AS [Test]
```

Comment: Paste your whole SQL please.

Comment: `CASE` is T-SQL is an **expression** that returns one of several values - it is ***not*** a flow control statement like in other languages. If you need to execute statements - use `IF` / `ELSE` instead

Comment: I haven't used IF/ELSE in sql so I'll definitely look into it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there just remove the `select` from `case statement`. Since all the values are coming from same table no need of `select` in case statement just keep `column name` it will fetch the corresponding column value.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Column1 = 'a' THEN Column2
         WHEN Column4 = 'b' THEN Column5
         ELSE Column6
       END AS [Test]
FROM   tableA
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get time and update you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.Column1 = 'a' THEN A.Column2
             WHEN A.Column4 = 'b' THEN A.Column5
             ELSE A.Column6
        END) AS [Test]
FROM TableA A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already inside a `SELECT`, so you do not need an additional `SELECT` inside:

```
SELECT
    ...
,   CASE WHEN TableA.Column1 = 'a' THEN TableA.Column2
         WHEN TableA.Column4 = 'b' THEN TableA.Column5

         ELSE TableA.Column6
    END AS [Test]
FROM
    TableA
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as:

```
select CASE WHEN TableA.Column1 = 'a' THEN TableA.Column2
     WHEN TableA.Column4 = 'b' THEN TableA.Column5
     ELSE TableA.Column6
END AS [Test]
from tableA
```

or even shorter in your case:

```
select CASE TableA.Column1 
     WHEN 'a' THEN TableA.Column2
     WHEN 'b' THEN TableA.Column5
     ELSE TableA.Column6
END AS [Test]
from tableA
```